# Put keyboard numeric in xaml - xamarin-forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<local:SportEntry x:Name="txtNumberCel" Font="Large" TextColor="Black" Opacity=".7" Text="{Binding Check}"
```

I want to show a keyboard numeric at the moment to insert a number in the texbox for Xamarin-Forms. I tried with InputScope="Number" and InputType="numberDecimal, but don´t work.

Can you anything idea?
Very Thanks!!!

Comment: I strongly suggest checking out the documentation in the future: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.InputView/ (which Entry inherits from)

Answer (score 4):

I assume this control inherits from [Entry](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry/):

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" ... />
```